# Proof of an algebraic fact

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to know a proof about the following algebraic fact.

**FACT:**
A polynomial of n degree have at least one root.

I have learnt this while knowing the proof of 'A polynomial of n degree have n roots.
Can anyone prove the fact I mentioned with better explanation?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) tells us:

> Every polynomial equation having complex coefficients and degree >=1 has at least one complex root. This theorem was first proven by Gauss.

There are proofs of the theorem on the Wikipedia page which I have linked to.